# Summernote remove image callback get image src on backspace

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I have a Summernote editor where users can add text and upload images as well I am using the below code to display all images src when the user clicks backspace.

```
callbacks: {
                onImageUpload: function(image) {

                    uploadImage(image[0]);
                },
                onMediaDelete: function(target) {
                    console.log(target[0].src)
                    deleteFile(target[0].src);
                },
                onInit: function() {
                    var $editable = $(this).siblings('.note-editor').find('.note-editable');
                    var lastImageSrc = null;

                    $editable.on('keydown', function(e) {
                        if (e.key === 'Backspace') {
                            var $images = $editable.find('img');
                            console.log($images.length);
                            $images.each(function() {
                                var $image = $(this);
                                console.log($image.attr('src'));
                                if (!$image.hasClass('note-image-ghost')) {
                                    $image.addClass('note-image-ghost');
                                    $image.attr('data-src', $image.attr('src'));
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                },

            },
```

But this is displaying all images when the user clicks backspace. I want to get only one image `src` data.
for example, if there are three images in the editor and the user clicks the cursor next to the second image and enters backspace then I want the second image src only.
how to do this? any help?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to be a clear, specific question in sentence format. Don't add tags. Also fix your formatting so your explanation isn't shown as code.